# SSR crashing in Next.js on unsuccessful GraphQL request (HTTP code 500) using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client

Well, I'm a little dumpy. I will try to explain my problem as clearly as possible.

I use Apollo client to do my GraphQL queries. I also use NextJS.
I have a page that needs to be rendered on the server side for SEO reasons.

So I have a `getProductFromSlug` function that allows me to execute my request.

```
export const getProductFromSlug = async (slug: string) => {
  try {
    const { data, error } = await apolloClient.query<{
      product: Product
    }>({
      query: GET_PRODUCT_BY_SLUG_QUERY,
      variables: {
        slug,
      },
    })

    if (error) {
      return { errors: [error.message] }
    }

    if (!('product' in data) || data.product === null) {
      return { errors: ['Product with specified url not found'] }
    }

    return {
      data,
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // @ts-ignore
    const formattedErrors: ApolloError = isApolloError(error)
      ? error.graphQLErrors.map((error) => error.message)
      : [`Unhandled error : ${error}`]

    return {
      errors: formattedErrors,
    }
  }
}
```

Here's `getServerSideProps` to pass data to page

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (
  context: GetServerSidePropsContext
) => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
  // @ts-ignore
  const requestData = await getProductFromSlug(context.params.slug as string)
  return 'errors' in requestData
    ? { notFound: true, props: requestData }
    : { props: requestData }
}
```

The problem is that when I have a HTTP code 500 from the endpoint, the SSR is crashing and on Vercel, it's causing a serverless crash error.

> Error: Response not successful: Received status code 500
> This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window

If needed, here's my entry point (_app.tsx):

```
function MyApp(props: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
      <RecoilRoot>
        <RecoilNexus />
        <AuthenticationFromStorage />
        <Layout>
          <props.Component {...props.pageProps} />
        </Layout>
      </RecoilRoot>
    </ApolloProvider>
  )
}
```

You can see my Apollo Client here : https://gist.github.com/SirMishaa/d67e7229307b77b43a0b594d0c9e6943

Stack trace of `yarn run dev` (next dev -p 3005) :

```
ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
    at Object.throwServerError (C:\Users\misha\Documents\dev\rekk-next\node_modules\@apollo\client\link\utils\utils.cjs:45:17)
    at C:\Users\misha\Documents\dev\rekk-next\node_modules\@apollo\client\link\http\http.cjs:31:19
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
error - uncaughtException: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

**NOTE** :
**After some try with console.log in try and catch scope, it shows nothing in the Next SSR console, so the internal error of Apollo is not caught for some reason.**

I appreciate your help, thank you!

[image]

Comment: How do you want to handle the 500 error on the frontend (as in what should be displayed to the user)? Isn't the error caught in the `catch` block enough?

Comment: Hi, no even with a try catch, ssr keep crashing

Comment: could you create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you can use this [URL](https://httpstat.us/500) as the graphql endpoint to get always a 500 error

Comment: What are the server logs showing in Vercel?

Comment: I created this [repo](https://github.com/diedu89/next-apollo-error) following the [guide](https://www.apollographql.com/blog/apollo-client/next-js/next-js-getting-started/) and put the same apollo client as yours except for the pusher link. It seems it works since I run `npx next dev -p 3005` with no errors. Maybe try running it without the pusher link and see what happens. However, to replicate it more accurately, please provide the versions of the packages you are using. It could be an issue for a specific version.

Comment: @diedu Thanks! I'm going to check your repo and if it still doesn't work, I'll make an minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @diedu You are right! The issue is caused by the PusherLink, without it, the catch of the error is working good! Thank you very much! If you want to put an answer in order to get the reputation bounty, don't hesitate

Comment: Would that be a solution for you? Don't you need the PusherLink? if you add the code for that link, I could continue digging into it

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the pusher link, I need it for subscription with Laravel Lighthouse over Web socket. 
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/9427
I don't know why with PusherLink, error are not handled

Comment: @SirMishaa I think you could overcome the build problem if you exclude the link when the code is executed in the backend as I mention in my answer, but you could get that error in the front end as well. I'll take a look at the PusherLink code and give it a try

Comment: Hey @SirMishaa, through some intense debugging, I figured out what the problem was. Could you take a look at my updated answer and try again

Comment: I'm going to try it ! Thanks a lot, you helped me a lot <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The issue was that [PusherLink](https://gist.github.com/SirMishaa/125b535e36fdc3e6751ba50b483010a6) was not continuing the execution in the chain when there was an error. Adding the `error` and `complete` handlers solved the problem.

```
      forward(operation).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
          ...
          this.subscribeToChannel(subscriptionChannel, observer)
        },
        // these two were missing
        error: (error) => observer.error(error),
        complete: () => observer.complete(),
      })
```

JIC, I also added a missing condition the code from the [other link](https://github.com/rmosolgo/graphql-ruby/blob/fca03eb8b5f1f67e2995f4543b01eefcb3276da5/javascript_client/src/subscriptions/PusherLink.ts#L76) taken as a reference has

```
    subscribeObservable.subscribe = (observerOrNext, onError, onComplete) => {
      if (typeof(observerOrNext) == "function") {
        prevSubscribe(observerOrNext, onError, onComplete)
      } else {
        prevSubscribe(observerOrNext)
      }
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Your code inside the catch block could be throwing an error, and that's what is breaking. I'm unsure about this condition `Array.isArray(apolloError)`, maybe you meant `Array.isArray(apolloError.graphQLErrors)`

You could try the `isApolloError` utility to be a little more clear and get some hints from TS types.

```js
import { isApolloError } from '@apollo/client';
...
        const formattedErrors = isApolloError(e)
          ? e.graphQLErrors.map(error => error.message)
          : [`Unhandled error : ${e}`];

        return {
          errors: formattedErrors,
        };
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response ! 
Indeed, isApolloError is cleaner but I still have the issue :/. 
My request is simple, I'm getting a Product entity from the endpoint using the slug of the page, when I enter an invalid slug, SSR is crashing because of the HTTP code 500 error (of the API). 

But it should absolutely not doing that, I'm using try / catch with your cleaner solution for the error handling... Any idea ?